How much harder does shooting Finns get when you're drunk?
In Noita, if you drink whiskey, your screen starts 'swimming' and aiming isn't 100% accurate anymore (according to the onhover status effect in-game).
Because it's amusing, I get drunk every chance I can. However, I don't really notice an accuracy debuff.
So how much does it actually hurt the player's aim? That is, what's the spread modifier percentage increase per percent of whiskey ingested? Or, you know, however Noita does it.

To see the accuracy debuff effects more clearly, try it with a spell-and-wand that is normally very accurate.  It should be obvious on a 0 spread wand with luminous drill, for example.
